# Inserting and deleting mismatching records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an asp.net web app where a user can update a table in a database.

I have a table that looks like this in SQL Server 2008:

```
lom_number(fk) problem   primarykey
1            AA       1
1            AA1      2
1            AA3      3
23           B        4
22           C        5
```

The user has a front end and can make changes to this data based on the `foreignkey`

The user can update data like this:

1. if target.foreignkey = source.foreignkey AND target.model  = source.model  then do nothing
2. if (foreignkey,model) in target do not exist in source, then delete the row
3. if (foreignkey,model) in source do not exist in target then insert it

So far I have this:

```
create procedure Merge_lom_problem
as
merge [dbo].lom_problem as target
using temp.lom_problem as SOURCE
on (target.lom_number = SOURCE.lom_number)
when matched and (target.problem <> SOURCE.problem)
insert (lom_number,problem) values (SOURCE.lom_number,SOURCE.problem)
when matched and
```

But I am having trouble with #2 and #3.

Can you please help to code it?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if your table sample fields matched your sql. Is Lom_problem the PK or is Lom_number?

Comment: @conrad very sorry! thank you for noting that. lom_number is FK

Comment: @ConradFrix you there my friend. please

Answer (score 0):

first problem u said do nothing right?

try this

```
create procedure Merge_lom_problem
as
merge [dbo].lom_problem as target
using temp.lom_problem as SOURCE
on (target.lom_number = SOURCE.lom_number)
--when matched and target.problem = SOURCE.problem then

when not matched by source then
DELETE

when not matched by target then
insert (lom_number,problem) values (SOURCE.lom_number,SOURCE.problem)
```

but i'm not really sure it will working because i'm not tested yet